# What does mterp mean?

Tags: android, virtual-machine, dalvik

There is a folder named `mterp` in the dalvik source code. Its path is `/vm/mterp`.
I want to know what does the word `mterp` mean?

Comment: It seems like a reasonable question. Let's keep this copy, but close the other one as a dup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'm' stands for "modular" -- mterp is the modular interpreter.

It was an evolution of the previous implementation, which was effectively a monster `switch` statement.  As noted in the mterp [README](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/mterp/README.txt):

> This is the source code for the Dalvik interpreter.  The core of the
>   original version was implemented as a single C function, but to
>   improve performance we rewrote it in assembly.  To make this and
>   future assembly ports easier and less error-prone, we used a modular
>   approach that allows development of platform-specific code one opcode
>   at a time.

The ability to switch implementations at opcode granularity was extremely valuable, because it allowed us to swap between C and assembly implementations with a quick change to a config file -- very handy if you suspected that something in the assembly version wasn't working quite right.  When we wanted to add floating point support, we just wrote new opcode pieces and created a new [config file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/mterp/config-armv5te-vfp) that replaced the float-dependent instructions.

The structure also makes [porting the interpreter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/docs/porting-guide.html) to entirely new platforms much easier, because you can evolve from the "portable" interpreter to a "fast" interpreter in bite-sized pieces.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Dalvik "mterp" README](https://www.assembla.com/code/android-gb-for-sharp-is01/git/nodes/debug/dalvik/vm/mterp/README.txt):

```
==== Overview ====

This is the source code for the Dalvik interpreter.
```

---

Apparently, `mterp` is the name for the interpreter used by Dalvik. It is a part of the VM and it directly executes or performs the code.

Comment: Yes, it is the interpreter. But what I want to know is that what does the letter `m` stand for?

Answer (score 0):

*mterp* is the module of dalvik vm interpreter

In a language VM, there are many modules in the VM such as HeapManager(GC), JNI(java native interface), Bytecode interpreter and so on.

Here mterp is the module of Bytecode interpreter. And you should know, Dalvik vm bytecode is the DEX format. And in the implementation of vm interpreter, mterp contains many different arches such as X86, arm, misp.

If you want to study this module, I suggest you overview the Dalvik VM's /docs/java-bytecode.html. And then study the mterp's c implementation.